How delete reference message using Disnake
I want to create command what delete reference message if command this answer to message what need delete. I tried use ctx because in docs ctx save attribute message but i get the problem what said css doesn't have attribute message. My cod:
    @bot.slash_command(name='delete_message', description='Для удаления сообщения введите эту команду ответом на сообщение, которое вы хотите удалить.')
    async def delete_message(self, ctx):
        db = sqlite3.connect(database)
        if ctx.message.reference:
            a = ctx.message.reference.message_id
            ctx.interaction.delete_message(a)
        db.commit()
        db.close()

problem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 1083, in call_param_func
    return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\utils.py", line 567, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\Pups_bot\cogs\Moderation.py", line 263, in delete_message
    if ctx.message.reference:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ApplicationCommandInteraction' object has no attribute 'message'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1378, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 737, in invoke
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ApplicationCommandInteraction' object has no attribute 'message'

